# Remove automatically added backslash infront of double quotes

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a text box where in my a xamarin ios application. User may enter double quotes .(") in this text box.I have to assign this values toa text box in  Web page through c#. When I add a text like   test" (note I have added double quotes at the end ), I could see that application assign test\" to the website.

How can I avoid this automatically added backslash?

Comment: You see this slash in the debugger, right?

Comment: In the debugger I found slash. But when I add it to browser also I could find the slash. So password checking in the website shows invalid credential due to slash

Comment: In order to store a double quote in a string it must be escaped, no way around that.

Comment: May be replace that "\"  with `password.Replace(@"\", "");` when you want to show it in browser or validation.